# How do you get Athena/Presto to recognize parquet index

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, amazon-athena, presto

I have a 25k "row" parquet file (totaling 469.5kb) where each item in the parquet has a unique integer id. Knowing this i've put an index on this column, but it doesn't appear indexing the column actually affects performance when using Athena (AWS service) / Presto (underlying engine). I'm trying a simple select from where where I want to pull one of the rows by it's id-

```
SELECT *
FROM widgets w
WHERE w.id = 1
```

The `id` column is indexed, so once Presto finds this match it shouldn't do any further scanning. The column is also ordered, so it *should* be able to do a binary search the resolve the location instead of a dumb scan.

I can tell if the index is being used properly since Athena returns the number of bytes scanned in the operation. With and without the index, Athena returns the byte size of the file itself as the scan size, meaning it scanned the entire file. Just to be sure, ordering so that the id was the very first row also didn't have an affect.

Is this not possible with the current version of Athena/Presto? I am using python, pandas, and pyarrow.

Comment: How (with which component) did you create the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify how you created the index, I assume you are talking about a Hive index. According to [1](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/3433) and [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/presto-users/ab3BKCkYf8k), Presto does not support Hive indexes. According to [3](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Indexing), Hive itself has dropped support for them in Hive 3.

That answers your question regarding why the presence of the index does not affect the way Presto executes the query. So what other ways are there to limit the amount of data that has to be processed?

- Parquet metadata includes the min and max values per row group for each column. If you have multiple row groups in your table, only those will be read that could potentially match.
- The upcoming [PARQUET-1201](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1201) feature will add page-level indexes to the Parquet files themselves.
- If you query specific columns, only those columns will be read.
- If your table is partitioned, filtering for the "partition by" column will only read that partition.

Please note, however, that all of these measures only make sense for data sizes sevaral orders of magnitude larger than 500KB. In fact, Parquet itself is an overkill for such small tables. The default size of a row group is 128MB and you are expected to have many row groups.

Comment: Thank you for that. I guess I'm just trying to tell prestodb that a particular column is unique and once it finds a match it doesn't need to query further. I am doing rollups on a data set that's much larger (30gb) and taking the results of that and joining in dimensional fields (widget name, etc.). I haven't done any partitioning yet but that would be my next step. So is there any way outside of that to label a column in parquet as _unique_?

Comment: Hive 3.0 will have UNIQUE (HIVE-16575), but Presto probably doesn't support that yet. You can try adding LIMIT 1 to your queries so that they stop after a match is found, but that will only save you 50% of time on average at best (there are also constant costs).